# How to check if a string is numeric?

Tags: java

I have a gpa program, and it works with the `equalsIgnoreCase()` method which compares two strings, the letter "a" to the user input, which checks if they put "a" or not. But now I want to add an exception with an error message that executes when a number is the input. I want the program to realize that the integer input is not the same as string and give an error message. Which methods can I use to compare a type *String* variable to input of type *int*, and throw exception?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[0-9]+").matches(string)`, perhaps?

Comment: So do you want to match *only* integers or any number?

Comment: i dont want them entering any number basically, just string

Answer (score 67):

Many options explored at http://www.coderanch.com/t/405258/java/java/String-IsNumeric

One more is

```
public boolean isNumeric(String s) {  
    return s != null && s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");  
}
```

Might be overkill but [Apache Commons NumberUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29) seems to have some helpers as well.

Comment: I would change the last "+" to a "*" so that `123.` becomes valid input (nothing after decimal delimiter is valid input)

Comment: I would add a check for NULL ... otherwise it will crash

Comment: @StefanMichev people should stop passing null arguments. It's not right for every method in the world to have a null, empty or whatever check.

Comment: This is easy code but millions of Java programmers have to write it.  It should be in that standard library.

Answer (score 34):

If you are allowed to use third party libraries, suggest the following.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html

```
NumberUtils.isDigits(str:String):boolean
NumberUtils.isNumber(str:String):boolean
```

Comment: You don't need 3rd party anything: loop: if(Character.isDigit(c))

Comment: Beware! isNumeric and isDigits only tackle pure numbers. i.e., they will return false for 7,574. (comma-separated numbers).

Comment: isNumber(str:String) is Deprecated

Answer (score 8):

Use this

```
public static boolean isNum(String strNum) {
    boolean ret = true;
    try {

        Double.parseDouble(strNum);

    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: try to catch other exceptions also :) 
if you sent a `Null` object string, this fails

Answer (score 6):

You can also use ApacheCommons StringUtils.isNumeric - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.String)

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but you don't need to add more software. In Java SE: loop: if(Character.isDigit(c))

Comment: Beware! isNumeric only tackles pure numbers. i.e., it will return false for 7,574. (comma-separated numbers).

Comment: Why does it return true for question marks? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 6):

Simple method:

```
public boolean isBlank(String value) {
    return (value == null || value.equals("") || value.equals("null") || value.trim().equals(""));
}


public boolean isOnlyNumber(String value) {
    boolean ret = false;
    if (!isBlank(value)) {
        ret = value.matches("^[0-9]+$");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use below method,

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
  try  
  {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
  }  
  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
  {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;  
}
```

If you want to use regular expression you can use as below,

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
  return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
}
```

Comment: Try-and catching an excpetion has such a huge overhead though.

Comment: Coding by exception is a known anti-pattern.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_by_exception and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: The method of using `Double.parseDouble()` isn't acceptable for internationalized coding situations. It will work reasonably well in the USA, but number strings with valid doubles in other countries will not necessarily parse correctly. For example, in some locales, the thousands separator can be a space " ", and "123 456" will cause a NumberFormatException even though it's a parseable number.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String string) {
    if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int stringLength = string.length();
    if (string.charAt(0) == '-') {
        if (stringLength > 1) {
            i++;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))
            || !Character.isDigit(string.charAt(stringLength - 1))) {
        return false;
    }
    i++;
    stringLength--;
    if (i >= stringLength) {
        return true;
    }
    for (; i < stringLength; i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))
                && string.charAt(i) != '.') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this little method lastly in my program so I can check if a string is numeric or at least every single char is a number.

```
private boolean isNumber(String text){
    if(text != null || !text.equals("")) {
        char[] characters = text.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (characters[i] < 48 || characters[i] > 57)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Character.isDigit(char ch) method or you can also use regular expression.

Below is the snippet:

```
public class CheckDigit {

private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Enter a String:");
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();

    if (CheckString(str)) {
        System.out.println(str + " is numeric");
    } else {
        System.out.println(str +" is not numeric");
    }
}

public static boolean CheckString(String str) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to check if the input *contains* a digit:

```
if (input.matches(".*\\d.*")) {
    // there's a digit somewhere in the input string 
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks, this helped, but m program still terminates after the exception throws. if I take out the exception, it runs perfectly...just the way I requested even if theres a number. any idea on how to still keep the prgm running after I thorw the exception

Comment: Wrap the code throwing the ex ration in a try-catch, catching the exception thrown.

Comment: I already tried just wrapping  my entirepart of the code which prompts inputs  in a try catch, but it didn't work, can u clarify using my posted code above

Comment: What code posted where? I can't see any code.

Answer (score 0):

To check for all int chars, you can simply use a double negative. 
if (!searchString.matches("[^0-9]+$")) ...

[^0-9]+$ checks to see if there are any characters that are not integer, so the test fails if it's true. Just NOT that and you get true on success.