# For loop and charAt problems, trying to determine whether a string is numeric

Tags: java, string

I want to write a program is for checking a real number, so i input "99aa", it says it is a right, but in fact, it should be wrong. i have check many time and i still can't fix the problem. can some one give me some hints?

```
public class jj {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        String num;

        // Create a Scanner object for console input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
        num = new String( input.nextLine() );

        for ( int i=0; i<=num.length(); i++ ) {
        int j = num.charAt(i);

            if (j>57 || j<42 || j==44 || j==47 ) {
            System.out.print("This is not a real number.");
            break;
            } else 

            System.out.print("This is a real number.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you will break your for loop at the first iteration ? If your input 99aa, you will check that 9 is a digit, print its a number and break your loop. In fact, every input that starts with a digit will print valid number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is numeric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206768/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric)

Comment: Your brackets are wrong. Your for loop terminates after one iteration, no matter what

Comment: are you considering `negative values` in real number ?

Comment: I'm voting to put on hold, as questions involving missing brackets are likely not of widespread interest to future readers. Nevertheless, there's plenty of answers below.

Answer (score 2):

I commented what's wrong with your logic but don't reinvent the wheel.

Use [`NumberUtils.isNumber`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html) from `org.apache.commons.lang.math.NumberUtils` :

> Checks whether the String a valid Java number.
>   Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the 0x qualifier, scientific notation and numbers marked with a type qualifier (e.g. 123L).

```
if(NumberUtils.isNumber(num)) 
     System.out.println("This is a valid number");
else        
     System.out.println("This is not a valid number");
```

Alternatively, if you want to check that you have only digits in your String, you can use
[`NumberUtils.isDigits`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isDigits%28java.lang.String%29):

> Checks whether the String contains only digit characters.

```
boolean valid = NumberUtils.isDigits(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

try this instead

```
if ((j >= 48 && j <= 57) || j==44 || j==47 ) {

}
```

You want to check whether it is between 48 (0) ***and*** 57 (9), boundaries included.

See the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Sidenotes:

- You're allowing `j==47`. 47 is `/`, dot is 46. What one do you want?
- Your second `break;` will leave the iteration after the first cycle.

Comment: Third sidenote : the for loop should be `for (int i=0; i<num.length(); i++ )`

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
  char ch = num.charAt(i);

  if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
       System.out.print("This is not a real number.");
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to point out some logic trouble that's giving you some fits:

```
if (j>57 || j<42 || j==44 || j==47 ) {
    System.out.print("This is not a real number.");
    break;
    } else 
        System.out.print("This is a real number.");
    break;
}
```

First of all, nevermind the problems with the `if` check.  Jeroen Vannevel's answer covers this.

After any number returns true on the `if` check, you print the error and `break;` the loop.  This is fine (assuming we fix the `if` check).  You don't need to check every digit if you know the first one is wrong, you can quit checking.

But your `else` prints a message guaranteeing that the whole number is real despite just checking a single letter.

And then the `break;` isn't contain in the `if` or the `else` (not your brackets and my indentation that makes it more clear).  No matter what happens, you'll `break;` after a single iteration.

What you need should look something more like this:

```
boolean numberFlag = true;
for ( int i=0; i<=num.length(); i++ ) {
    int j = num.charAt(i);

    if ((j >= 48 && j <= 57) || j==44 || j==47 ) {
        numberFlag = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(numberFlag) {
    // logic when a valid number is checked
} else {
    // logic when an invalid number is checked
}
```

We can't say whether `num` is a valid number of not until we've checked every single character in the string.

---

And please be sure to check @ZouZou's answer, as this is what you should really be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about this in terms of Characters and implement the following:

```
if (Character.isDigit(num.charAt(i))) {
//do something
}
```