# Take input and then cast into appropriate data type - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method that takes input of any data type from user and then cast that input into a variable type. But my code always returns string type. any fix required?

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
Object a = x.next();
```

here's my method for detecting the object type

```
public static String inputValidator(Object input)
{
    if(input.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.String"))
    {
        return "string";
    }
    else if(input.getClass().getName().equals("java.lang.Integer"))
    {
        return "integer";
    }
    return "nor";


}
```

Comment: Bytes can be interpreted as anything.

Comment: [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) returns a `String`. Java is strongly typed, not duck typed. This does not work.

Comment: okay so what part of my code need to be changed? I guess taking the input. what should I write instead?

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of how you would like this to work?  What output you want for what input?

Comment: I'm trying to take input 'anything' from the user which will be assigned as Object and will detect the classType.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is numeric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206768/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric)

Comment: If this is a learning exercise, then great, carry on.  If your trying to do something productive use Commons CLI  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Answer (score 3):

That's not a correct way since [Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) returns a `String`. If you are looking for primitives or some 'basic' types then you could use an appropriate method like [nextByte()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte()) or [nextBigDecimal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigDecimal()).

I.e. with your current implementation you will not ever get to the `else if` block which checks for `Integer`.

If you are mostly interested in numbers please check this:
[How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-numeric-type-in-java)

> lets say String ,int and double only

If performance is not that much of an issue and you are looking for a simplistic solution then I would suggest to go with:

```
if (isInteger(string)) {
    // is an integer
} else if (isDouble(string)) {
    // is a double 
} else {
    // is a string
}

public static boolean isDouble(String string) {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean isInteger(String string) {
    try {
        double d = Integer.parseInt(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

NOTE: call order matters here, you have to call isInteger() before isDouble() cause integer string is also a double string.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? probably another question mentioned by @Barett could help?

Comment: please have a look at my updated post, "I'm trying to take input 'anything' from the user which will be assigned as Object and will detect the classType"

Comment: @Munna as I have mentioned before all you get is a `String`. Do you intend to be able to recognize integers, doubles, booleans, dates etc..? I would say that you have to define a list of types you want to check for.

Comment: exactly I want to be able to recognize. how can i achieve so?

Comment: @Munna could you provide a complete list of types you want to be able to parse?

Comment: lets say String ,int and double only