# How to check if a string is made only of letters and numbers

Tags: java

Let's say a user inputs text. How does one check that the corresponding `String` is made up of only letters and numbers?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringValidation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter your password");
       String name = in.nextLine();
       (inert here)
```

Comment: Option 1: loop through the string and check each character individually. Option 2: regular expressions: `name.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*");` - assuming you mean normal letters, not accented characters or anything like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is numeric?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206768/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric)

Answer (score 23):

You can call `matches` function on the string object. Something like

```
str.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*")
```

This method will return true if the string only contains letters or numbers.

Tutorial on String.matches: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm

Regex tester and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/kM7sB7/1

Answer (score 5):

1. Use regular expressions :

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}+");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
   if (!matcher.matches()) {
       // found invalid char
   }
   ```
2. for loop and no regular expressions :

   ```
   for (char c : name.toCharArray()) {
       if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
           // found invalid char
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Both methods will match upper and lowercase letters and numbers but not negative or floating point numbers

Answer (score 5):

Modify the Regular expression from `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

```
String text="abcABC983";
System.out.println(text.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"));
```

Current output: `true`

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression character class `\p{Alnum}` can be used in conjunction with [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)). It is equivalent to `[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

```
boolean allLettersAndNumbers = str.matches("\\p{Alnum}*");
// Change * to + to not accept empty String
```

See the [`Pattern` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).