# Strings as sentinel values in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I'm trying to write a program that asks the user if they want to enter a real number. If yes, then prompt the user to enter a number. Keep prompting for number inputs until user says "no." Once this happens, output the average of the numbers entered.

I think I'm stuck trying to implement a string for the sentinel value. I want the sentinel value to be "no." But with this last attempt I have here, when I enter "yes" I get an InputMismatchException. Also, not sure if this is a job for do/while or just while. Kind of new to all this and not sure how to go about this, as we don't have examples of using strings for sentinels.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int count = 0;
float total = 0;        
float inputNumber;


Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );

System.out.println("Want to enter a number?");

String reply = "";


inputNumber = scan.nextFloat();

do {
    reply = scan.nextLine();
    if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number > ");

        total+= inputNumber ;
        count++ ;

        System.out.println("Enter another number, or " +
                "enter \"no\" to terminate > " );
        inputNumber = scan.nextFloat(); 
    }
}   
while (! reply.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) ;

if (count != 0) {
    System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + 
            (total / count));
}

}
```

}

Comment: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](//stackoverflow.com/a/13102066)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Though that is related, the main problem is having is not related to that. It's more to do with trying to use `nextFloat` to read the string "no".

Comment: `nextFloat()` cannot store a String. Store the number to a String and cast it to a float.

Comment: @Sweeper Ok, I see it now. OP has 2 issues.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove first `inputNumber = scan.nextFloat();`
- Fix loop.
- Add `scan.nextLine()` after `scan.nextFloat()`

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        float total = 0f;
        float inputNumber = 0f;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );

        System.out.println("Want to enter a number?");
        String reply = scan.nextLine();

        while (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number > ");
            inputNumber = scan.nextFloat();
            scan.nextLine();
            total += inputNumber;
            count++;

            System.out.println("Enter another number, or enter \"no\" to terminate > ");
            reply = scan.nextLine();
        }

        if (count != 0) {
            System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + (total / count));
        }
    }
```

---

### EDIT

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        float total = 0f;
        float inputNumber = 0f;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );

        System.out.println("Want to enter a number?");
        String reply = scan.nextLine();

        if (!reply.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            return;

        System.out.println("Enter a number > ");
        while (!reply.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            reply = scan.nextLine();
            try {
                inputNumber = Float.parseFloat(reply);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                continue;
            }
            total += inputNumber;
            count++;
            System.out.println("Enter another number, or enter \"no\" to terminate > ");
        }
        if (count != 0) {
            System.out.println("The average of the numbers is " + (total / count));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If they enter a number you will exit the while loop at `reply = scan.nextLine()`. 
You would be better checking `!reply.eqaulsIsnoreCase("no))`. 

You then need to handle when reply is a number, cast it to a float, add it to the total and update the count.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'm unfamiliar with try/catch. I've read up on it just now and I think I'm starting to see why it's useful here; is there a way to do this without try/catch, though?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to verify your input. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206768/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric